# Select min value of a field with $min and aggregate in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to get document with all fields for the aggregation of $min with particular field in my collection.

Below is my collection structure,

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("585e7454b0a2683a0f6a3617"),
"postid":100,
"region" : "IN",
"brand" : "Uber",
"used" : 4
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("585e7454b0a2683a0f6a35b7"),
"postid":101,
"region" : "UK",
"brand" : "Airbnb",
"used" : 7
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("585e7454b0a2683a0f6a3619"),
"postid":102,
"region" : "US",
"brand" : "Uber",
"used" : 9
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("585e7454b0a2683a0f6a3619"),
"postid":103,
"region" : "US",
"brand" : "Airbnb",
"used" : 2
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("585e7454b0a2683a0f6a3619"),
"postid":104,
"region" : "US",
"brand" : "Home",
"used" : 17
}
```

I want to get distinct value of brand of a document with $min value of 'used' field.

I want to get output like this,

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("585e7454b0a2683a0f6a3617"),
"postid":100,
"region" : "IN",
"brand" : "Uber",
"used" : 4
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("585e7454b0a2683a0f6a3619"),
"postid":103,
"region" : "US",
"brand" : "Airbnb",
"used" : 2
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("585e7454b0a2683a0f6a3619"),
"postid":104,
"region" : "US",
"brand" : "Home",
"used" : 17
}
```

Currently I am using this query for this,

```
db.sales.aggregate(
[
 {
   $group:
     {
       _id: "$brand",
       used: { $min: "$used" }
     }
 }
]
);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

If you want to include the other fields in the group, better use the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** or **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)** accumulators but after ordering your documents. In this case you'd want to use the **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** operator as your first pipeline step first then group afterwards with the documents in ascending order:

```
db.sales.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "brand": 1, "used": 1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$brand",
            "postid": { "$first": "$postid" },
            "region": { "$first": "$region" },
            "docId": { "$first": "$_id" },
            "used": { "$first": "$used" }
        }
    }
])
```